# How to remove a project in GitLab from "Your projects"?

Tags: gitlab

I have been invited to several GitLab projects that were created by others and some of them are still actively used. However, they are not relevant at all any longer for me. Is there a way how I can remove a project from my view in "Your projects" without deleting the whole project for others? I just don't want to see them [image]any more in my "Your projects" menu.

Update: Here is a screenshot of my line in the member's list. I can't see any "Leave" button or anything similar.

**Reminder**: Does anybody have a suggestion? I'll appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can `leave` projects! Simply, go to the `Project Information` tab and, under the `Members` section, there is a list. Find your account and press the `Leave` button!

Comment: Thanks Marco for your answer. Unfortunately there is not "Leave" button anywhere inthe members list

Comment: @PeterBeit should be in the end of the line that corresponds to your account. it is a red button with a returning arrow. if you hover on it with the mouse, it is labeled as "leave"

Comment: Thanks Marco for your comment. I can't see anything. I uploaded a screenshot in my question

Comment: that's very very strange. maybe you are the owner of the project and you have to make somebody else the owner, since the project can't stay without one

Comment: There are at least 10 other owners. I also tried it with another Web-Browser. In none of the projects there is anything like a "Leave" button

Comment: wait, is that a project in your namespace? in that case it's more complicated. you should move it to another namespace, but i don't know if it can be directly done

Comment: What do you mean by "your namespace"? All those projects are listed under "Your projects". I did not create any of them.

Comment: when you create a project, you have to choose a namespace. if they are in your namespace (every user has a namespace) you can't leave them. but looks like they're not in your namespace. allow me to say it's very very strange

Comment: Thanks Marco for your comment. Acutally I have to admit that I have no clue about these namespaces. I did not create the projects and I don't even know what a namespace is and how I can use it. Anyways, do you have another idea how to leave a project in GitLab? It's very strange if there is indeed no option for leaving a project without deleting it.

Comment: at this point, you have to contact one of the owners of the project and ask them to revoke your account permission on each repository

Comment: Thanks for your comment Marco. There are more than 10 owner for some projects (and I am always one of them). Which owner are you referring to that has the right to remove me from the project? And is there no other way how I can remove myself from the project or at least make the projects not listed in my view?

Comment: i think any owner has the permission to remove you. anyway, no. sadly, there isn't a feature to hide a project. this is very strange that you can't leave projects, tho